# Spring - Inject null instead of throwing an exception when bean is not found

Tags: java, spring

I have an injection in my class

```
@Inject IMyInterface controller;
```

But there are no classes implementing IMyInterface. How can I make spring inject null instead of throwing `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` because I don't necessarily need it to be present?

Comment: +1 Nice twist on typical question asking why Spring is injecting null (when it really isn't).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `@Inject` (Assuming it is [`javax.inject.Inject`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Inject.html)), I think there is no direct way to make the binding optional. But if you use `@Autowired`, you can set it's `required` attribute to `false`:

```
@Autowired(required = false)
IMyInterface controller;
```

Comment: Alright. I think the specification should add such thing

Comment: @ibrabeicker [It has very clearly added that thing](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation). That too within a **Note**.

Comment: the java CDI specification, not Spring's

Comment: @ibrabeicker Ok. I don't know whether it's mentioned there or not, but I would expect that.

Comment: JSR-330 has `Provider<T>` for optional injection, which is extended in CDI by `Instance<T>`