# How setup spring to inject null instead of throwing exception for all @Autowired annotations?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22258843/spring-inject-null-instead-of-throwing-an-exception-when-bean-is-not-found) about injection null instead of throwing exception. Is there a way to setup spring to set this behaviour as default one? E.g. modifing each annotation is cumbersome.

Comment: The right way is to change the annotations. Or don't use field injected (as that is bad for multiple reasons). Use constructor injection for required dependencies and setter injection for optional dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

May be you can change the @Autowired annotation to the following,

```
@Autowired(required = false)
```

Now, If the bean is not initialized then there should be no NullPointerException.