# How to avoid NoSuchBeanDefinitionException when I don't need a Bean instance?

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I don't know if I'm dealing the right way with the problem. So, help me there. I have a legacy project that I'm trying to migrate to Spring. There are a lot of problems I can't solve. One of them is that I have some validators that are called in different contexts, they are injected. Something like:

```
public interface PreValidator<E extends MyAbstractEntity> {}
public interface PosValidator<E extends MyAbstractEntity> {}
```

Inside another bean I have a list of these validators. Something like this:

```
public class OneEntityService extends MyAbstractService<OneEntity> {
    @Autowired
    public OneEntityService(List<PreValidator<OneEntity>> preValidators, 
                            List<PosValidator<OneEntity>> posValidators) { ... }
}
```

And this is perfect, because Spring inject the list of all validadors in the constructor. But in some cases I don't want to create those validators. The `MyAbstractService` apply those validators, but I can control if it's null. This is not a problem.

The problem is that when Spring try to create those beans it throws a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException forcing me to create some dummy validators. I don't want to create those dummy validators. Is there a way to avoid the exception?

Comment: If you tell Spring to autowire a bean it will attempt to do so. Your question is unclear. Are you expecting Spring to somehow know you aren't actually going to use the bean?

Comment: Try `@Autowired(required=false)` like suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22258893/105224

Comment: @Andreas_D thank you a lot. Can we close this question?

Comment: I'd keep it open. Maybe it helps somebody else who's looking for an answer to a similiar question.